# Can QEMU emulate PCIe link bandwidth as well?

Tags: qemu, pci-e

Is QEMU's PCIe only functional emulation?

Or is it possible to emulate the actual bandwidth?

For example, if it is set to 1-lane PCIe, does it emulate a PCIe link with a bandwidth of 1GB/s?

If it is set to 4-lane PCIe, does it have a bandwidth of 4GB/s?